# Why am I getting "script not responding" warning

Tags: support, firefox

Why am I getting "script not responding" warning for script `http://sstatic.net/so/js/master.js?v=5005:1` when viewing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675138/running-nunit-task-in-cruisecontrol-net-always-throws-errors) with Firefox 3.5.5

**Edit 1**: I flushed the cache. Still getting the same warning.

**Edit 2**: Running Firefox in safe mode does fix the problem.

Comment: Have you flushed your cache?

Comment: Ctrl+F5 is your friend!

Comment: Run FireFox in Safe Mode. Does that help?

Comment: Unable to replicate on **Opera.** Then again, the called JS file is without the trailing colon (`:1`) on it.

Comment: When Safe Mode works, the culprit is one of your add-ons. Are you using Firebug?

Answer (score 1):

That trailing colon is very bizarre and doesn't appear in our source code.

At any rate, if safe mode fixes it, one of the add-ins is at fault.

Comment: Looks like what's needed here ***puts on sunglasses*** is a flushed colon.